# jQuery $.load Not Executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am currently using jQuery on my Django site to reload a div once a user clicks a button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var post_list = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("post_container"))
    for(var post in post_list){
        post_list[post].id = 'post' + post;
    }
    var $arrows = $(".arrow");
    $arrows.each(function(index){
        var data = $(this).data();
        var element = $(this);
        element.on('click', function(event){
            if(user_auth){
                var currentParentElement = element.parent().parent().parent().get(0);
                var id = $(currentParentElement).attr('id');
                $(id).load(document.URL + ' ' + id);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

From the console I can see that `currentParentElement` and `id` are pointing to the correct div to reload, but `$(id).load()` does not seem to be doing anything.

In the image linked below, the clicking the arrow buttons should make the green or red number change. The number does not change when the arrow is clicked, but it does change when I reload the  entire page. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T26wn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ID selector is missing the `#` symbol.  For example, suppose the `id` of this target element is `"myID"`:

```
var id = $(currentParentElement).attr('id');
```

Then the jQuery selector you're using is:

```
$('myID')
```

Which is looking for a `<myID>` element.  There isn't one, so no matches are found, so there's nothing to call `.load()` on.

You could add the symbol to your selector:

```
$('#' + id).load(document.URL + ' #' + id);
```

(Note: The same correction was also made in the selector passed to `load()` for the same reason.)

Comment: I have made that edit and now the div is reloading, but now all of its contents disappear when it is triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: @Duncan: You'll probably want to open your browser's debugging tools and check the response from the server in the AJAX request.  See what it contains and what element therein has that ID.

Comment: I cannot find anything within the debugging tools indicating that anything went wrong with the function. After clicking the button, the page is left with `<li class="post_container" id="post0"></li>` with no contents inside. Do I need to add the contents to the $.load function in order for them to be included?

Comment: @Duncan: When you debug, what is the exact runtime value of `id`?  In the response from the server, is there an element with that `id`?  What does that element contain?

Comment: The id was `post0` for the first post in the list, which is correct. In the AJAX response however, the id is not present on any of the posts but the content is present. In the actual page, the id is present for all of the posts and the content is missing from the items where the button was pressed,

Comment: @Duncan: If that ID is not present in the AJAX response then your logic is wrong.  I don't know what information you're looking for in that response, but it sounds like it either isn't there or isn't in the format you expect.  Time to examine your data and re-think how you are interacting with it.